# MongoDB NumberLong display in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Currently i am working on  `MongoDB` collection data in to `PHP` table , in my `MongoDB` collection have following data

```
> db.AETOM.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : {
        "UCODE" : NumberLong("413010192215382"),
        "DCODE" : NumberLong("990004908640390")
    },
    "Total" : 14
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "UCODE" : NumberLong("413010192171534"),
        "DCODE" : NumberLong("990004393658160")
    },
    "Total" : 562
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "UCODE" : NumberLong("413011193047063"),
        "DCODE" : NumberLong("990004298968470")
    },
    "Total" : 99
}
```

and this is the code i use for the display the records

```
<?php

        $m = new MongoClient();
        $db = $m->selectDB('MapData');
        $collection = new MongoCollection($db,'AETOM');

        $cursor = $collection->find();
        $cursor->limit(10);
        echo "<html><head></head><body>";
        $data  = "<table style='border:1px solid red;";
        $data .= "border-collapse:collapse' border='1px'>";
        $data .= "<thead>";
        $data .= "<tr>";
        $data .= "<th>UCODE</th>";
        $data .= "<th>DCODE</th>";
        $data .= "<th>Total</th>";
        $data .= "</tr>";
        $data .= "</thead>";
        $data .= "<tbody>";
        foreach($cursor as $document) {
            $data .= "<tr>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["UCODE"] . "</td>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["DCODE"] . "</td>";
            $data .= "<td>" . $document["Total"]."</td>";
            $data .= "</tr>";
        }
        $data .= "</tbody>";
        $data .= "</table>";
        echo $data;
        echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

when i run it , it shows only "Total" value , UCODE and DCODE fields doesn't show anything , when i check it with terminal it show below error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: UCODE in
>   /var/www/html/MongoDBT/test2.php on line 23
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: DCODE in
>   /var/www/html/MongoDBT/test2.php on line 22

please kindly help me to fix the issue.

Comment: try with `$document["_id"]["UCODE"]` and `$document["_id"]["DCODE"]` and tell working or not?

Comment: yes , it working :) , thank you very much

Comment: Kavinda glad to help you. cheers :):):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since  `UCODE` and `DCODE` comes inside `_id` array, so to fetch them you have to do like below:-*

```
$document["_id"]["UCODE"]  instead of $document["UCODE"]
```

AND

```
$document["_id"]["DCODE"] instead of $document["DCODE"]
```